# Is $e^{z}$ a one to one function?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ , $z = x+iy ; x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

$e^{z} = e^{x+iy}$ and that will become $e^{x}(\cos({y})+i\sin({y}))$

but then I know cosine and sine are periodic, both trigonometric functions aren't one-to-one function at all.

Therefore complex exponential isn't one to one function.

Is this correctly done?

Comment: You need only find a counter example. Consider $y_1=0$ and $y_2=2\pi$, for instance.

Comment: $\cos(0) = \cos(2\pi) = 1$ ,  $\sin(0) = \sin(2\pi) = 0$

Comment: @coffeemath No, I mean to consider two different $y_i$ as the imaginary parts of some complex number $z$.

Comment: Does this solution answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21195/798113

Comment: @user170231 I see your point--- removed my comment.

Answer (score 2):

No. If it was injective then $\exp(2\pi xi)$ would be also injective but the latter function takes value 1 infinitely many times by the Euler formula.

Comment: so did I do it correctly?

Comment: I just looked at your post. Yes it is correct.

Comment: Now I am thinking about it what if cosine and sine are restricted, then it will be one to one. If it isn't, it isn't one to one.

Comment: What does it mean "restricted cos"?

Comment: $\exp z$ is locally injective, that is every point has a neighborhood where the function is injective.

Comment: what you mean locally injective? Does the multiple of values of domain have the same output in the range.

Comment: I gave the definition of locally injective.